# Unity UI button; foreach loop with lists for color and name

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

So Im trying to make an UI list with buttons to change color in Unity. In this script I have 2 lists 1 for Color and 1 for the name, for the buttons I try to spawn. To spawn these buttons i use foreach loops. Yet If I put the for each loop in an other, I get way more buttons than wanted. Or I get the right amount of buttons, but the buttons will have the last name in the list.
In the script i have commented out the thing i tried..

```
public GameObject ContentPanel;
public GameObject ListItemPrefab;

// List 
public List<Color> ColorOptions;
public List<string> ColorNames;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    foreach(Color color in ColorOptions){
        //Too much buttons
        //foreach (string name in ColorNames){
            //Spawn button
            GameObject newButton = Instantiate(ListItemPrefab) as GameObject;
            // Get button component
            ButtonController controller = newButton.GetComponent<ButtonController>();
            // Give button the color from the list 
            newButton.GetComponent<Image>().color = color;
            controller.Name.text = name;
            newButton.transform.SetParent(ContentPanel.transform);
            newButton.transform.localScale = Vector3.one;

            //List with the names
            //Buttons get the same name
            /*foreach (string name in ColorNames){
                controller.Name.text = name;
            }*/
        //}
    }
}
```

In the buttoncontroller is a var Name for the button text. Anyway my question is then: **How do I get the names from the list without multiplying the buttons ?** I hope you guys can help me with this !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code will create as many buttons as the ColorOptions will be available with corresponding names -

```
public GameObject ContentPanel;
public GameObject ListItemPrefab;

// List of color option and corresponding names
public List<Color> ColorOptions;
public List<string> ColorNames;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    for(int count=0;count<ColorOptions.Count;count++){
        //Spawn button
        GameObject newButton = Instantiate(ListItemPrefab) as GameObject;
        // Get button component
        ButtonController controller = newButton.GetComponent<ButtonController>();
        // Give button the color from the list 
        newButton.GetComponent<Image>().color = ColorOptions[count];
        // Give button the name from the list
        controller.Name.text = ColorNames[count];
        newButton.transform.SetParent(ContentPanel.transform);
        newButton.transform.localScale = Vector3.one;
    }
}
```

So, if you have 5 color options and their corresponding names then you'll get 5 buttons.

Comment: You might want to use a 'for' loop for that

Comment: Thanks @spatbord. Good catch. It was a typo.